# Spring boot endpoint path

Tags: java, spring-boot, path, mapping, endpoint

I have some issues with my IntelliJ project. I'm trying to hit a endpoint with Postman but I don't even know what is the path to do so! I tried every path possible and nothing works! Just got 404 status.
Here's my restController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/cities")
public class CityService extends GenericService<City> {

    @Autowired
    private CityRepository cityRepository;

    /**
     * Method that returns all the cities.
     * @return {@link List<City>}
     */
    @Override
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<City> loadAll(){
        System.out.println(new Date() + " Called LOAD-ALL.");
        return cityRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

My genericService:

```
public class GenericService<T> {

    @Autowired
    GenericRepository<T> genericRepository;

    public GenericRepository<T> getGenericRepository(){
        return genericRepository;
    }

    /**
     * Method that returns all the generic entities.
     * @return {@link List<T>}
     */
    @GetMapping
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<T> loadAll(){
        System.out.println(new Date() + " Called LOAD-ALL.");
        return getGenericRepository().findAll();
    }
```

My config.properties:

```
spring.application.name = authorization-service
server.servlet.context-path = /authorization/api
#server.context-path = /authorization/api
#server.contextPath = /authorization/api
#server.module-path=/

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl = true
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

server.port = 8787

eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=${EUREKA_URI:http://localhost:8761/eureka}

eureka.instance.instance.instance-id = ${spring.application.name}:${server.port}:${random.int}

spring.cloud.loadbalancer.ribbon.enabled = false

spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_database? 
createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username = someUser
spring.datasource.password = somePass
```

I was trying to use this link on Postman http://localhost:8787/authorization/api/cities but nothing works.
Someone can help me please? I'm kinda new on this thing of mapping endpoints.
I'm using Spring Boot 2.2.2.RELEASE.
The startup message is

```
2020-01-18 09:06:10.023  INFO 2808 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8787 (http) with context path '/authorization/api'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with the property.

```
server.servlet.context-path = /authorization/api
```

Also when the spring boot application starts up , the context path will be displayed in the logs as something below

> [2m2020-01-18 08:41:04.513[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13986[0;39m
>   [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m
>   [36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m
>   Tomcat started on port(s): **8080 (http) with context path
>   '/authorization/api'**

Also the following

```
@GetMapping
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "")
```

means the same. Please check [@GetMapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/GetMapping.html)

**Update**
Op had issues with Component scan and Controller classes were not auto detected .

Comment: Tried this but got the same issue. I also removed the "@GetMapping" and the "value = ''" because sounds redundant but still getting 404. And when i make a call like https://localhost:8787/authorization/api/cities he hits my back-end but says that he can't parse a HTTP charachter on the requested path or something.

Comment: What is the context path logged when the application starts up ? Please update the question with the error and the latest code you tried with and spring boot version

Comment: 2020-01-18 09:06:10.023  INFO 2808 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8787 (http) with context path '/authorization/api'
This is the path that logged to me!

Comment: what happens when you use a browser to hit this url ? Also , can you try modifying the method as follows

    @Override
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loadAll(){
        return "test";
    }

Comment: I've tried exactly as you recommended and the same happens.
Browser response:

Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sat Jan 18 09:57:36 BRT 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

Comment: Make sure the '@RestController' falls in the radar of '@ComponentScan'

Comment: How can i do this? There's a way to see which controllers are on the component scan?

Comment: Make sure @SpringBootApplication annotation is at the top package level . Else @ComponentScan(basePackages ={“package”}) on the class you run. Basically making sure your Controller gets autodetected when the app starts up

Comment: Finnally that works!! I was using my folders like this: com.xxx.main.AuthenticationMain.class.
Now i'm using as com.xxx.AuthenticationMain.class and that works out! Now i have some problems with the GenericRepository but at least the endpoints are responding correctly! Thanks @R.G!

Comment: Great !! Glad that I could help . If it was componentscan that created issues , shall I update the answer and you can mark it closed ?

Comment: Yes please!! The problem really was the @ComponentScan! Hope this question help someone else like me! Thanks again R.G!